Segmentation fault when calling printf in x86-64 assembly on WSL
            .intel_syntax noprefix

            .data
b:          .byte 9
s:          .word 0
l:          .long 0
q:          .quad 0
format:     .asciz "%s"
text:       .asciz "Hello world!"

            .text
            .global main
main:   
            push rbx /* stack needs to be 16 bytes aligned */
            mov rdi, format /* first argument to printf */
            mov rsi, text /* second argument to printf */
            mov rax, 0 /* no parameters in a vector register */
            call printf
            pop rbx /* restore stack pointer */
            ret

Windows 11, WSL
Compiling: gcc -g -no-pie -O0 -o sandbox.elf ./sandbox.s
Running: ./sandbox.elf
Result: Segmentation fault
I think my code respects System V ABI. Why am I getting segmentation fault?

mov rdi, format is a load in GAS .intel_syntax, unlike NASM.  You want lea rdi, [format + rip].  (Or worse, movabs rdi, offset format).  As you can see with a debugger like GDB, RDI isn't a pointer to your format string and isn't even a 48-bit pointer correctly sign-extended to 64.

Ah yes...Thank you!

mov rdi, offset format works too.

Oh right, I forgot you were using -no-pie, so the most efficient way is mov edi, offset format.  And 7-byte mov rdi, sign_extended_imm32 like mov rdi, offset format works as well, but would be a waste of machine-code bytes vs. 5-byte mov edi, imm32.

Speaking of efficiency, the calling convention only uses AL to hold the number of XMM arg regs, not the full RAX.  But either way, xor eax,eax is the most efficient way to zero AL, and also zeroes the full RAX.
